# MongoDB - modify and copy a document in a different once it is inserted in the first one

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm using the mongoDB kafka connector from kafka connect to read a kafka topic in order to insert data to a mongoDB collection.

Here an example of my connector :

```
{
  "name": "order-mongodb-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "database":"Trade",
    "collection":"Order",
    "topics":"Order",
    "connection.uri":"{{mongodb-uri}}",
    "mongo.errors.tolerance": "all",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing": "true",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type": "allowlist",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list": "date,orderId"
  }
}
```

After the document is inserted to the collection, I would also like to insert this same document in another collection with some some modification made to it.

The initial idea was to code a kafka stream application that would connect to this topic transform the event and write the new one in a new topic on which I would put a sink connector similar to the one above. It sounds complicated.

I was wondering if I could directly use a mongoDB feature like a trigger that would do that.

I came across the [post processor feature](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/fundamentals/post-processors/#std-label-sink-post-processors-modify-data) of the kafka connect mongoDB sink but it doesn't seem to allow writing to a different collection.

Comment: The Kafka Stream approach is the most common, but you can use other tools to consume, modify and produce data to new topics and/or write to Mongo directly.

Comment: Create two sink connectors - one for the first collection, and another for the second collection.  Assuming they can be asynchronous you could actually insert into both at the same time.